# controlling VST instruments from Ruby

Tags: ruby, midi, vst, midi-instrument

I've recently bought a copy of EZDrummer, a VST plugin that acts as a virtual drumkit. I'd really like to hook into it from Ruby code so that I can create loops and drum patterns programmatically. To be honest I am not sure even where to start. Presumably I have to create a VST host which can load the plugin and then hook into it somehow. I am a Ruby developer so that's the language I'd be looking to implement this in. Any pointers in the right direction?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122709

Comment: Thanks Michael, the route of running a VST host within a Ruby process might be the way to go. Although I am wondering if I can use jVstHost from within JRuby in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you bought a VST plugin, I assume you have some sort of DAW as well. Before you start trying to host a VST from within ruby, try the following smaller projects:

1. Generate a MIDI file from ruby. Load
   the MIDI file into your DAW, and
   play.
2. Stream live MIDI data from your ruby
   process to your DAW. On Windows, you
   can do this with ReWire, on OSX, you
   can create an IAC bus in the Audio /
   MIDI setup app.

If you need more direct control of EZDrummer than this allows you, then go down the path of trying to host the VST from within Ruby.

Comment: Thanks for that, and while tinkering with jVSTHost for a few hours here and there with no luck loading a plugin let alone getting Ruby involved, I shall be following your advice. Cheers, James.